# how to get client IP address of USER_Login from AIX audit log

Tags: logging, aix, audit

From `AIX` audit log of user login, I am getting like below:

```
USER_Login root OK Wed Jan 31 13:51:45 2007 tsm user:
root tty: /dev/pts/2
```

I can only get the `tty#`, but how can I get the `IP` address from where the user login?

Answer (score 0):

The command "last" should show you the ip address and timestamp of when they log in and out.